# Huge React State Array with Hundreds of Inputs, slow state changes onChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, state, onchange

I'm trying to a large React form, but each input in the form is complex and has a complex state. I keep the state of all of the inputs in a `parent` component, and each input is wrapped in a `child` component. I have a state array in parent that contains the current value of the state for all of the input elements. Currently, every time there's an `onChange` in the input, I try to reset the entire state array in the parent via `setState()`. This was okay with up to 5 inputs, but once I got above that (like a hundred inputs), I started to notice some serious lag in the program. **Please note**: **the program will also allow you to rearrange, `delete`, and `add` inputs, so the state needs to accommodate those changes** Ie. the first input could swap positions with the 2nd input or be inserted right after the 10th input.

My objective is to find a way to optimize the performance of this onChange. Ultimately, I don't really need the data to be in the `parent` component, I just need to collect the values for the inputs when I click `save` at the bottom of the page.

Just to reiterate, I have two components.

1. A Parent Component
2. A Child Component

The Child component is basically an `input` where users can write hundreds of lines of text.

The Parent component contains 100s of the children and essentially looks like this:

```
export default function Parent(props) {
  const [state, setState] = useState(createDummyData());
  useEffect(() => {});



  const onInputChange = (value, index) => {
    var tempValue = [...state];
    tempValue[index] = value;
    setState(tempValue);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column" }}>
        {state.map((item, index) => (
          <Child
            value={state[index].content}
            index={index}
            onChange={onInputChange}
          />
        ))}
        <button style={{backgroundColor: "red"}}>save input data</button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

The child component looks like this

```
export default function Child(props) {
  useEffect(() => {});

  const onChange = event => {
    props.onChange(event.target.value, props.index);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <input value={props.value} onChange={onChange} />
    </>
  );
}
```

I haven't found a simple way around this. Some seem to suggest using Redux, others seem to say use a combination of `useMemo` and `useEffect` to prevent rerenders. Your help would be much appreciated.

One thing I noticed is that if I try to keep individual state within the Child components, they render `onChange` much faster. This is probably because it doesn't have to setState for the parent state array each time. If possible, I'd like to be able to simply go through and grab the state of the child nodes when I click save. Would I use a `ref` in this case? Is it possible to do it without a ref?

I'd also like to AVOID using `onBlur()` just for the purpose of this project

The codesandbox is copied down below for reference: https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-knuth-jm8n6?fontsize=14

Comment: You don't set keys which is a major contributor to the lag

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Created example with similar functional components and dummy data:

https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-cdn-q4vx0

Have to create Child component with local item state and sync with main array.
Added Delete and Add.

Work with object  arrays as your sample.

Comment: I have a slight question, I have to make the state an array, not a map because inputs can be added or deleted. How would you modify this so that it could accomplish this?

Comment: Did you try to  delete prop in existing map like: : delete state[keyfield],  you also can work with array but you need some field for key unique  value  for each row.

Comment: I udpdate the answer with your code and add delete and update

Comment: Thank you!!!! This is amazing! Just a quick question. I'm a little confused as to how you were able to just do:
const onInputChange = (index, item) => {
    state[index] = item;
}; Isn't state supposed to be immutable? Aren't you supposed to use setState()?

Comment: Yes you are right but in this case I just want to sync new instance from child item to parent array without rerender whole array, only for sync.

Comment: the thing is that here you are not actually updating the state using set state, so you don't really solve the performance problem, the app starts to lag only when you are setting new state

Comment: How about using a useRef() for state in the parent when we are only using it for syncing with a new instance?

Answer (score 3):

Copying large arrays shouldn't be the culprit, it only copies object references which is usually very fast, not an actual deep copy. In fact, [Redux itself](https://redux.js.org/faq/performance#do-i-have-to-deep-clone-my-state-in-a-reducer-isnt-copying-my-state-going-to-be-slow) does it this way.

The reason you're experiencing this lag is you didn't set keys to the children. You should set unique keys and don't use the index as the key.

Comment: this is nothing to do with the keys

Answer (score 1):

I'd minimize the re-renders, so I'd do following:

1. Keep all functions in parent and share memoized callback to avoid redundant function constructions
2. Do not use indexes to figure out specific children
3. Memoize the children

You can check out the code with implemented removal by the link https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-rgb-cejoy?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark&file=/src/Parent.jsx

That way, you reduce the re-renders almost to zero and you're good to go until you face the penalties of copying and rendering really large arrays which I guess you are not likely to run into

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options:

1. Add `key` to the `Child`, e.g., email, firstName, lastName, allowing React to only re-render changed input(s). Prefer not to use `index` for the `key`, otherwise inserting/deleting item at the being of the state array will cause the entire list to re-render

   ```
   {state.map((item, index) => (
     <Child
       // e.g., email, firstName, lastName, prefer not to use `index`
       key={item.name}
       value={item.content}
       index={index}
       onChange={onInputChange}
     />
   ))}
   ```
2. As you mention the `state` array is huge, you should not use `.map()` anymore, instead you should utilise libraries such as [react-virtualized](https://bvaughn.github.io/react-virtualized/#/components/List), which will only render visible elements to the DOM and greatly improve your performance.